# How to use an EditText, defined in xml, in a programmatically built page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am busy building a fragment completely programmatically, including a ScrollView, and LinearLayouts, with a number of EditText fields.
These latter fields need to have rounded corners, which are defined in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/visitorLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_rounded"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/admin_code_numbers2"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
    android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout is called like this:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_language_detail, container, false);
```

But again, I am only interested in the EditText, not in the surrounding linearlayout, that's done in the code.

The EditText is created like this and is non-null:

> EditText editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_rounded);

However, when I add this with addView to a LinearLayout I get an illegal state exception.

Question-1: how can I combine building up a complex GUI programmatically and create several EditText fields, defined in xml?

Question-2: how does my EditText xml needs to look like? Does it need to be embedded in a container like LinearLayout, that I don't need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Define your `EditText` in it's own xml file.
2. Use `LayoutInflater` to inflate the `EditText`
3. Add that programmatically to the `LinearLayout`

Repeat step 2 and 3.

Layout for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@string/admin_code_numbers2"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Inflating a view:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

EditText edit = (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.layout.myEditText, null);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time! I did step 1 and use the file name to do this (within a for-loop): EditText editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.layout.fragment_visitor_detail); But how do I, in step 2, combine LayoutInflater with editText?

Comment: Updated answer, you can also find more information of inflating views searching google

Comment: Thanks, that extra block of code was the breakthrough. Thanks everybody for the contribution!

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate components from xml and add them programmatically to your layout, however to avoid the `IllegalStateException` you must first remove View from its parent View.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_rounded);
rootView.removeView(editText);

anotherView.add(editText);
```

Comment: But I need to use editText repeatedly within a for-loop, adding every one of them to the container (like LinearLayout or TableLayout).

Comment: So you want to add several `EditText`s to a container within one iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inflate the same EditText again and again.
That will defenitely throw Illegal state Exception.

If you want to create multilpe EditText,you can create them through code like

```
EditText editText =new EditText(context);
editText.setBackground(R.drawable.round_corner);
```

You can set whatever you want to this edittext and add it to a layout you inflated already.

your round_corner.xml should be placed in drawable folder and it should look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"
             /> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Comment: I know and have that working. But the point is I wanted to add rounded corners to the EditText, via xml. The question is how to do that?

Comment: after creating your Edittext give editText.setBackground(R.drawable.round_corner);